# Disable autoplay-policy for Chrome for certain hosts/doimains only

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, autoplay

Autoplay of audio without any user interaction has been blocked on most browsers for a good while now, which is really good. Is there however a way to manually whitelist hosts/domains that don't follow this policy in Chrome?

For example I develop/host a small application on my local machine which I just want to do its thing but I still don't want autoplay on the rest of the web. And if possible I don't want multiple Chrome instances with different launch parameters ...

I've been looking through the Chrome flags/settings and docs, but couldn't find anything useful. Same for older questions on SO: They all seem outdated.

Comment: Does adding the site in chrome://settings/content/sound help?

Comment: @TobiasK. I recommend you put that into an answer and collect your bounty. Wow.

Comment: Gladly, I wasn't sure whether it works, but happy it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the site/domain in:

`chrome://settings/content/sound`

This seems to also allow autoplay and not just audio in general.